# Is an empty type bad design?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am Csharpening my skills, coming from Python, and am exploring generics. I have a small "playground" set up in unity where I have the following:

```
        NM          (NM) - sends power between machines
| PM |--||--| PM |  (PM) - distributes power internally
| CC |      | CC |  (CC) - consumes power
| CC |      | CC |       - generates power
```

A Machine has components that consume and generate "power".
A Power Manager (PM) knows of all the components (CC) in the machine and handles the distribution of power in the machine.

I then wanted to distribute power between different machines, and so I wrote a NetworkManager (NM) class such that each distinct network of connected machines had its own manager. Power managers can then send and request power to and from other machines on the "network".

The next logical step was to make it generic, so that I wasn't limited to just power. Maybe I wanted to send water or heat. I made two classes to replace PowerManager and the power-only NetworkManager:

```
ResourceManager<TResource> where TResource : Resource { ... }

NetworkManager<TResource> where TResource : Resource { ... }
```

This seems great because now a manager can be created to handle any resource needed by the machine. However, the alarm bell here is that my `Resource` superclass and its subclasses are completely empty. I don't need them for anything other than the fact that they are a type, defining what resource the managers handle. I considered a "stringly typed" approach by trying `new ResourceManager("power")` and matching resource type based on string name but it doesn't feel rigid and I'd like to avoid compile-time errors that could arise from spelling mistakes etc.

So, **to summarize**: how do I do the equivalent of creating a `new ResourceManager<Electricity>()` without creating an empty `Electricity : Resource` class? Or is that an acceptable way to approach the issue? I feel like I might be stretching the intentions of generics.

Comment: This is basically just a version of the Special Case Pattern and something I do frequently. I also find that empty types rarely stay empty.

Comment: So it has a name! That's a good sign. You're probably right in saying it won't remain empty as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing inherently wrong with it.   Other options would be to create an interface (ie. IResource) that your Resource class implements as can others if necessary then you simply have:

```
ResourceManager<IResource>
NetworkManager<IResource>
```

Some benefits you get with the Interface include being able to use mocking when running unit tests against your code.

Comment: I considered doing that, but realized I didn't have any functions to put in it (at the time). However, as James mentioned in his comment it most likely wont remain empty for long, so I'll mark this as correct.